# Don't work ion-scroll zoming

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making simple image view have zoom/scroll(xy). but i can't got correct result by using ion-scroll. i am sorry, I am new on ionic. 
Here is my .js code part and class.

JS

```
<ion-content class="bg-color detail-cont">

    <ion-scroll class="filter-image" zooming="true" direction="xy" min-zoom="1" locked="false" has-bouncing="true">
        <div class="my-image" style="background: url('{{ getCurPhotoURI() }}')"></div>
    </ion-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.filter-image {
    height:100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: black;
}
.my-image{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center, center !important;
}
```

What's wrong?
Thank you for advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the zooming is just not working? This is because the you haven't set the `overflow-scroll` property to `false`. For some reason, when you don't set this to false, the `ion-scroll` element won't be able to detect zooming.

So your code would look like this:

```
<ion-content class="bg-color detail-cont">

<ion-scroll class="filter-image" overflow-scroll="false" zooming="true" direction="xy" min-zoom="1" locked="false" has-bouncing="true">
    <div class="my-image" style="background: url('{{ getCurPhotoURI() }}')"></div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Android 6.0.1, Ionic 1.3.1. Code from Ionic [example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) with `overflow-scroll="false"`